# Is there a way to improve big-json's performance when stringifying a big JSON?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I've tried `big-json` to stringify JSONs that exceed V8's limit and it worked fine.

Problem now is that it takes so much longer than normal `JSON.stringify`, I understand the tradeoff, but is there any way I can improve the performance?

Here's the code I have so far.

````js
   const stringifyStream = json.createStringifyStream({
      body: payload,
    });

    stringifyStream.on("data", function (strChunk) {
      console.log("Received str chunk");
      console.log(strChunk);
      dataReceived += strChunk;
    });

    stringifyStream.on("end", function () {
      console.log("Finished receiving the data.");
      console.log("POJO" + dataReceived);
    )};

    ```
````

Comment: Kindly mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: Edited the post, thanks.

Comment: What is your system configuration?

Comment: You are asking about a very specific library. The library does not provide any way to do so out of the box unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just send smaller JSON,.  IOW: chunk the data..?